# How to create a multi module spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have 2 maven packages, both of them with spring boot dependencies.
CoreApplication and CustomerApplication. Both apps have Spring MVC controllers, views and static resources.

In CoreApplication I dont have any runner class annotated with @SpringBootApplication.

In CustomerApplication pom.xml I use CoreApplication as a dependency.

If I run the CustomerApplication @SpringBootApplication annotated runner class, it finds the controllers in CoreApplication, but not the views. It can serve requests like http://localhost:8080/core/index, but I get an error from thymeleaf. (org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index")

Is it possible what I want to do? How can I have a Core module with all common app specific stuff and a Customer app for every customer with their own business logic?

Comment: Is it required that `CoreApplication` does not have `@SpringBootApplication` annotation?

Comment: No, it was just my idea, that I can use it as a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try:

Annotate your `CoreApplication` module with `@SpringBootApplication` to let Spring manage and initialize your app as usual:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CoreApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And in your `CustomerApplication`'s runner, you can put:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CustomerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(CoreApplication.class, CustomerApplication.class)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

This way Spring will initialize your two modules properly.