# Load static content from an embedded jar

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot

Is it possible to load UI (Static content) of an embedded jar? Example I have a fat jar `main.jar` which runs(UI as well) on `localhost:8080` . Within `main.jar` I have another jar `b.jar` embedded. `b.jar's` static content is an Angular JS application, which I want to load while launching `main.jar`. Like there can be a button in nav bar of `main.jar` UI which would navigate to `b.jar` UI.
Is it possible to do it?
I don't want to have static files of `b.jar` in main project.

Comment: you can make b.jar as a webjar

Comment: is your b.jar a spring boot application?

Comment: Hi, I need to implement the same solution, is this possible through wejar?

Answer (score 0):

If your two modules are Spring  boot application, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49403241/5695673) answer which may correspond to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load the nested's jar static content if it's in the below list of directories

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

But you may face the issue here which has not been fixed yet even with the latest spring boot 2 release https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8324